# Displaying filename in report without extension

Tags: ms-access, filenames, attachment

I would like to make a continuous report in access that shows the filename of an attachment field without the extension. Does anyone know how? Here is what I've tried.

```
= Left([attachmentfield].[FileName];(Len([attachmentfield].[FileName]) - InStrRev([attachmentfield].[FileName];".")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need Len() function. InStrRev() returns number of characters from beginning (not end) to "." which serves as length value. Also, remove `]` and `[` on each side of period. Access adds them if field selected from field list or dropdown so have to edit.

`=Left([attachmentfield.FileName], InStrRev([attachmentfield.FileName], ".") - 1)`

Expression will have #Type! error if there is no item in field. If there are multiple items, attachment field will expand so each filename displays as a separate record.

Comment: Thanks for this correction. It does not fix my problem though. I get a #Name? error.

Comment: See revised answer.